# How to move Stored Payment Methods Component to Account Information Page

Tags: magento2

I tried moving the Stored Payment Methods Block of the module vault (Original at) `(vendor/magento/module-vault/view/frontend/templates/cards_list.phtml)` to the Account Information Block of the module customer. (Original at) `(vendor/magento/module-customer/view/frontend/templates/account/dashboard/info.phtml)`

In `customer_account_index.xml` I did:

```
<referenceBlock name="customer_account_dashboard_info">
  <block class="Magento\Vault\Block\Customer\CreditCards" name="vault.cards.list" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Vault::cards_list.phtml" />
</referenceBlock>
```

And then in `info.phtml`:

```
 <!-- Stored Payment Method Code -->
 <?php echo $block->getChildHtml('vault.cards.list'); ?>
```

but by doing this only its header is displayed and the card details aren't. I'm not sure what is wrong. Below I have attached the Screenshot.

For reference, In `cards_list.phtml` file the code responsible to render the body of the card details is

```
<tbody>
   <?php
   foreach ($tokens as $token) {
     echo $block->renderTokenHtml($token);
    }
   ?>
 </tbody>
```

I've tried different methods of moving but still, it isn't showing up. I've also moved other components this way and it has worked for me in the past.

What I would've to do for the card details to also show up.

The file responsible to render card details is at `vendor/magento/module-vault/view/frontend/templates/customer_account/credit_card.phtml`

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The block `vault.cards.list` is responsible for rendering cards list is located in the `vendor/magento/module-vault/view/frontend/layout/`**`vault_cards_listaction.xml`**

The template responsible for rendering card details is located in the `vendor/magento/module-vault/view/frontend/templates/customer_account/credit_card.phtml` file.
In the Magento default, this template belongs to

- the `paybraintree.card.renderer` block, which is defined in the `vendor/paypal/module-braintree-core/view/frontend/layout/`**`vault_cards_listaction.xml`** file in the Paypal Braintree Core module.

```
<referenceBlock name="vault.cards.list">
    <block class="PayPal\Braintree\Block\Customer\CardRenderer" name="braintree.card.renderer" template="Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

- the `payflow.card.renderer` block, which is defined in the `vendor/magento/module-paypal/view/frontend/layout/`**`vault_cards_listaction.xml`** file in the Paypal module.

```
<referenceBlock name="vault.cards.list">
    <block class="Magento\Paypal\Block\Payflow\Customer\CardRenderer" name="payflow.card.renderer" template="Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

As shown, the `braintree.card.renderer` and the `payflow.card.renderer` blocks reference the `vault.cards.list` block to render their content within the `vault.cards.list` block.

Therefore, to add the `Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml` template to your `vault.cards.list` block in the Account information page, you have to define the `braintree.card.renderer` and the `payflow.card.renderer` blocks within the `vault.cards.list` block in your account index layout (`customer_account_index.xml`).

Your `vault.cards.list` block should be like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Vault\Block\Customer\CreditCards" name="vault.cards.list" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Vault::cards_list.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Paypal\Block\Payflow\Customer\CardRenderer" name="payflow.card.renderer" template="Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
    <block class="PayPal\Braintree\Block\Customer\CardRenderer" name="braintree.card.renderer" template="Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
</block>
```

In case you using a third-party extension that has a block reference the `vault.cards.list` block to render its content within the `vault.cards.list block`:
`<module dir>/view/frontend/layout/`**`vault_cards_listaction.xml`**:

```
<referenceBlock name="vault.cards.list">
    <block class="Magetu\Payment\Block\Customer\CardRenderer" name="magetu.card.renderer" template="Magetu_Payment::vault/customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
</referenceBlock>
```

You can do the same like I mentioned for the Paypal and Paypal Braintree Core modules. Your `vault.cards.list` block should be like this:

```
<block class="Magento\Vault\Block\Customer\CreditCards" name="vault.cards.list" cacheable="false" template="Magento_Vault::cards_list.phtml">
    <block class="Magento\Paypal\Block\Payflow\Customer\CardRenderer" name="payflow.card.renderer" template="Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
    <block class="PayPal\Braintree\Block\Customer\CardRenderer" name="braintree.card.renderer" template="Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
    <block class="Magetu\Payment\Block\Customer\CardRenderer" name="magetu.card.renderer" template="Magetu_Payment::vault/customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>
</block>
```

Comment: I tried this but this doesn't work either.

Comment: There is another block references the `vault.cards.list` in the Braintree module. Could you add the following block inside the `vault.cards.list` block I provided in my answer?
`<block class="PayPal\Braintree\Block\Customer\CardRenderer" name="braintree.card.renderer" template="Magento_Vault::customer_account/credit_card.phtml"/>`

Comment: nope that didn't work either

Comment: I haven't setup the payment method that supports Store Payment Methods, so I'll try to write the instructions here to help you debug. Which payment method you are using? Please add this code `var_dump(get_class($block));die;` on line 11 in the `vendor/magento/module-vault/view/frontend/templates/customer_account/credit_card.phtml` file and then visit the **Stored Payment Methods** page to get the output? It will help me know which block is rendering `credit_card.phtml` template file.

Comment: And please replace the `foreach` code in the `vendor/magento/module-vault/view/frontend/templates/cards_list.phtml` file with the following code `foreach ($tokens as $token) {
    var_dump($token);
}
die;`, and visit the Account information page to get output and paste it in somewhere like paste.org and share me the link to debug.

Comment: I found the file responsible for rendering `credit_card.phtml` turns out its the USAePay at `vendor/rootways/module-usaepay/view/frontend/templates/vault/customer_account/credit_card.phtml`. I tried moving this but find no luck. I know this is the file cuz i edited and saw my changes. Can you help me move it.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/147955/discussion-between-tu-van-and-sara-whitmore).